# Дополнительные права файлов в git

Tags: git

Допустим, я создаю файл с правами 644, затем делаю коммит с этим файлом

Вывод git 2.27.0:

```
create mode 100644
```

Что означают первые две цифры(10)?

Comment: Вот список флагов st_mode http://cmcmsu.info/2course/unix.file.attributes.htm

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt#L63-L72

Comment: @andreymal а что же тогда означает mode 160***, который можно увидеть при добавлении подмодуля?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

для начала: [git — это адресуемая содержимым файловая система](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) (подробности описаны по ссылке):

> git is a content-addressable **filesystem**

---

условно говоря, внутри каждого git-хранилища содержится информация про объекты эдакой «виртуальной файловой системы».

при клонировании (точнее, при выполнении команды *checkout*) на основании этой информации создаются объекты **реальной** файловой системы: файлы, каталоги, символические ссылки (поддерживаются многие файловые системы, далеко не только posix-совместимые).

так уж исторически сложилось, что эта виртуальная файловая система довольна похожа на множество файловых систем, соответствующих [стандарту *posix*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (первоначальный разработчик программы *git* является и первоначальным разработчиком программы *linux*, в которой почти сразу была реализована поддержка собственной posix-совместимой [ф.с. *ext*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext)).

в частности, стандартом определена [структура `stat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html), содержащая информацию про объекты файловой системы, в том числе и поле `st_mode`, содержащее и тип объекта, и права доступа к нему. тип объекта задаётся константами (`S_IFDIR` и т.п.), конкретные значения которых стандартом не определены.

---

в «виртуальной файловой системе» программы *git* используются только следующие типы файловых объектов (в документации [упомянуто даже меньше](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt#L63-L72)):

```
040000 объект типа tree   (из него создаётся каталог)
100xxx объект типа blob   (из него создаётся обычный файл,
                           xxx может быть 755 или 644 — права доступа к файлу)
120000 объект типа blob   (из него создаётся символическая ссылка)
160000 объект типа commit (из него создаётся пустой каталог)
```

последний из типов объектов используется как точка подключения под-модуля («git submodule»). в документации носит название «gitlink».

**резюмируя**: это не «дополнительные права», а дополнительная информация про объект файловой системы (пусть и виртуальной в данном случае), описывающая его тип.

---

увидеть типы объектов можно с помощью команды:

```
$ git ls-tree ссылка [каталог]
```

где ссылка — это хэш коммита, имя ветки или метки (в т.ч. `HEAD`).

---

кстати, с помощью присутствующей в *gnu/coreutils* программы *stat* можно увидеть полное содержимое поля `st_mode` для объектов реальной файловой системы:

```
$ stat -c '%f' файл 
81a4
```

это в шестнадцатиричной системе. а переведя в восьмиричную, увидим знакомые:

```
$ echo 'obase=8;ibase=16;81A4' | bc
100644
```

Answer (score 2):

Режим (mode) файла в unix содержит не только права доступа в виде привычных 3-х цифр, но и дополнительные флаги: является ли файл обычным, символической ссылкой, сокетом, каталогом или устройством. В частности `10xxxx` обозначает обычный файл, а `12xxxx` - символическую ссылку.

Подробности: http://cmcmsu.info/2course/unix.file.attributes.htm

Из всего этого многообразия git использует

- `100xxx` - обычный файл
- `120xxx` - символическая ссылка
- `160xxx` - gitlink (сам пока не знаю что это)

Подробности: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/index-format.txt#L63-L72

Таким образом `mode 100644` обозначает обычный файл с правами `644`

Comment: Разрешение 160*** можно заметить при добавления подмодуля в репозиторий